# How to create a mean line for a Line chart in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am able to create a Line Chart using a TSV line chart. Now i want to create a mean value Line parallel to x-axis. Please help how to do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%y");

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("line.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Time Difference (sec)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);


});

function type(d) {
  d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

date    close
0           1
19-09-15    11
20-09-15    12
21-09-15    2
22-09-15    20
23-09-15    13
24-09-15    4
25-09-15    4
26-09-15    5
27-09-15    1
28-08-16    32
29-08-16    23
01-08-16    12
02-08-16    5
03-08-16    4
04-08-16    10
05-08-16    20
06-08-16    22
07-08-16    1
08-08-16    3

Answer (score 1):

In regards to why what you have done does not work, you are trying to get an element on your page which is identifiable by:

```
("document.getElementByID(‘TextBoxProductName’).value = arguments[0]", "John")
```

You probably dont have an element which has that identifiable trait?

When you want to find an element which has an id, you know its going to be unique, so you can quickly/shortly and directly target it as:

```
element(by.id('TextBoxProductName'))

// or in shorthand
$(#TextBoxProductName)
```

to send enter text into it, use sendKeys:

```
$(#TextBoxProductName).sendKeys('John')
```

Please let us know if the problem you are having isnt the sending of keys, but rather the targeting of the element and we can work on maybe a solution to do with the popup box

Comment: Yes, problem is not sending the keys, but i am not able to find the element in the POPUP. Its a  new window popup and there are 2 HTML in it.

Comment: you can see the detail here  "Cannot switch to POPUP window in Protractor" in the question itself. 

I have tried everything i can but nothing happened as i am not able to focus on the window popup.

so 2 HTML are there in 1 POPUP. 
i can locate and work on the outer HTML but not able to work on inner html which is a form and complete html is defined in my earlier question as mentioned  in summary.

please have a look and let me know for any queries